# Implicit Process creation when pushing a Spring boot application

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-foundry

I am pushing a minimalistic Spring Boot web application on Cloud Foundry. My manifest looks like

```
---
applications:
- name: training-app
  path: target/spring-boot-initial-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
  instances: 1
  memory: 1G
  buildpacks:
    - java_buildpack     
  env:
    TRAINING_KEY_3: from manifest
```

When I push the application with **Java Buildpack** (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/tag/v4.45) , I see that it is creating an additional process of type `-task` which  does not have any running instance though.

```
name:                training-app
requested state:     started
isolation segment:   trial
routes:              ***************************
last uploaded:       Thu 20 Jan 21:29:31 IST 2022
stack:               cflinuxfs3
buildpacks:          
isolation segment:   trial
    name             version                                                                     detect output   buildpack name
    java_buildpack   v4.45-offline-https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#f1b695a0   java            java

type:            web
sidecars:        
instances:       1/1
memory usage:    1024M
start command:   JAVA_OPTS="-agentpath:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE=printHeapHistogram=1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMPDIR -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$(nproc)
                 -Djava.ext.dirs=$PWD/.java-buildpack/container_security_provider:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/lib/ext -Djava.security.properties=$PWD/.java-buildpack/java_security/java.security $JAVA_OPTS" &&
                 CALCULATED_MEMORY=$($PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-3.13.0_RELEASE -totMemory=$MEMORY_LIMIT -loadedClasses=13109 -poolType=metaspace -stackThreads=250 -vmOptions="$JAVA_OPTS") && echo JVM Memory Configuration:
                 $CALCULATED_MEMORY && JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $CALCULATED_MEMORY" && MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2 SERVER_PORT=$PORT eval exec $PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $PWD/. org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
     state     since                  cpu    memory        disk         details
#0   running   2022-01-20T15:59:55Z   0.0%   62.2M of 1G   130M of 1G   

type:            task
sidecars:        
instances:       0/0
memory usage:    1024M
start command:   JAVA_OPTS="-agentpath:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE=printHeapHistogram=1 -Djava.io.tmpdir=$TMPDIR -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=$(nproc)
                 -Djava.ext.dirs=$PWD/.java-buildpack/container_security_provider:$PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/lib/ext -Djava.security.properties=$PWD/.java-buildpack/java_security/java.security $JAVA_OPTS" &&
                 CALCULATED_MEMORY=$($PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java-buildpack-memory-calculator-3.13.0_RELEASE -totMemory=$MEMORY_LIMIT -loadedClasses=13109 -poolType=metaspace -stackThreads=250 -vmOptions="$JAVA_OPTS") && echo JVM Memory Configuration:
                 $CALCULATED_MEMORY && JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $CALCULATED_MEMORY" && MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2 SERVER_PORT=$PORT eval exec $PWD/.java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -cp $PWD/. org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
There are no running instances of this process.
```

I understand that it is a Springboot Web application , and that corresponds to the process of type `web` , however I do not know

- Who is creating the process of type `task`
- What is the purpose of this process ?

It would be great of someone is able to help me here.

Regards
AM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Who is creating the process of type task

[The buildpack creates both](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/623c819842925d4a0d44d0b2bba3edd361e7dee9/lib/java_buildpack/buildpack.rb#L104-L108). This is what's been happening for a while, but recent cf cli changes are making this more visible.

> What is the purpose of this process ?

I didn't add that into the buildpack so I can't 100% say its purpose, but I believe it is meant to be used in conjunction with running Java apps ask tasks on CF.

See [this commit](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/commit/88208f7943a8bfda768c378bdfc5193e53e7128d).

When you run a task, there is a `--process` flag to the `cf run-task` command which can be used to set a process to use as the command template. I believe the idea is that you'd set it to `task` so it can use that command to run your ask. See [here for reference to that flag](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/using-tasks.html#run-tasks-v7).